# Split questions for [YAML] and [YAML-css]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

At this time, [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml) has two meanings.  From the tag wiki:

> YAML: YAML Ain't Markup Language. YAML is a human friendly data serialization standard for all programming languages.
>
> In some cases it can also refer to YAML: Yet Another Multicolumn Layout. An open source CSS framework. See http://www.yaml.de

There is currently a (mostly-empty) [yaml-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yaml-css), where I think the css-related questions should be moved.

Comment: Be careful; some questions relate to both YAML-the-data-format and CSS, but do not relate to YAML-the-layout-framework, despite having both [tag:yaml] and [tag:css].